# Trying to superimpose positive and negative part of sinwave together

Tags: python, numpy

I'm learning numpy, logical indexing, and matplot. And I am doing this question which wants you to have the positive part of the sine wave red and negative part green. And then superimpose them. I was thinking of some ways to do this, but I need some help.

This is what I have:

```
t = np.arange(0.0, 5.0, 1e-2)
freq = 3.0
signal = np.sin(2*np.pi*freq*t)
plt.figure()

posthresh = signal > 0
pos = signal[posthresh]
negthresh = signal <0
neg = signal[negthresh]
plt.plot(t,pos,'r-')
plt.plot(t,neg,'g-')
plt.show()
```

This is what I had but clearly it isn't working. I was also thinking of another way where for the positive part I remove all the indices where signal < 0. But I'm having trouble with numpy doing that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple things to consider here. First, the error you likely got with the example code you posted mentions that: "x and y must have same first dimension".

To fix this, you'll need to perform the same logical indexing on the `t` array that you do for the `pos`/`neg` arrays:

```
plt.plot(t[posthresh],pos,'r-')
plt.plot(t[negthresh],neg,'g-')
```

Once that's fixed, you'll get a plot, but probably not the one you're looking for:
[image: resulting plot]

`plt.plot()` draws a connected line (when using the `'-'` markerstyle), which means that all of the gaps get connected together.

To fix this new problem, you can take advantage of the way matplotlib handles NaN values (it ignores them, and breaks the line until the next non-NaN). You can see this behavior like so:

```
pos = np.where(posthresh, signal, np.nan)
neg = np.where(negthresh, signal, np.nan)

# note that t.shape == pos.shape now, so we don't need to index t
plt.plot(t, pos, 'r-')
plt.plot(t, neg, 'g-')
plt.show()
```

[image: lines with gaps]

This still isn't exactly what you need, but we're getting closer. Note that the broken edges of each line aren't quite getting to zero, because of two issues:

1. The threshold conditions you chose are `> 0` and `< 0`, which doesn't include exactly zero values.
2. The sampling rate doesn't always produce exactly zero values at each period.

With a frequency of 3, the signal will cross zero at multiples of `t/6`, so you should make sure your sampling rate includes each of those values:

```
# sample at 1/60 to get 10 points between each zero crossing
t = np.arange(0., 5., 1/60.)
```

We'll also tweak the conditions to account for floating point error:

```
pos = np.where(signal > -1e-8, signal, np.nan)
neg = np.where(signal < 1e-8, signal, np.nan)
```

And the result looks great!

[image: final image]